# Ошибка при отправке RCON команды на сервер CS 1.6 через библиотеку python-valve

Tags: python

OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.8.1

Код из официальной [документации](https://python-valve.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rcon.html):

```html
import valve.rcon
address = ("ип адрес сервера", порт)
password = "пароль RCON"
with valve.rcon.RCON(address, password) as rcon:
    response = rcon.execute("команда пример: status")
    print(response.text)
```

Выводит ошибку: [image: ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

Не верный пароль или запрет на подключение к RCON